Using “rampaged” as an adjective?
Is there any context or example in English of “rampaged” being used as an adjective?
Can I, in any circumstances, use “rampaged” to describe a person:

“Frenzied”
“Acting wildly”
“Being unhinged”
“Or being emotionally unstable”?

Examples:

“He was acting like an rampaged man.”
“She had a rampaged look in her eyes.”
“His behavior was rampaged and unpredictable.”

Artificial told me that “unhinged”, “frenzied” or “wild” are much better here.
In understand and agree with this. But, I am not looking for a better solution. I am asking, if there is any situation in which I can use “rampaged” as an adjective? Or will it be an unconditional language mistake?

Why not just "rampaging"? If I encountered "rampaged man," clearly it's an intentional mis-use, but I would take it as using an intransitive verb in a transitive way to mean the victim of a rampage.

Past participles used as adjectives typically mean that something is done to the noun they modify: a painted wall is a wall that has been painted, not a wall that somehow paints things; a destroyed city is a city that has been destroyed, not that destroys something else. So the verb usually has to be transitive although there are some exceptions. But rampaged isn't normally used like this; of course you're free to write anything you like and nobody will arrest you for it, but maybe they won't understand it.

@AndyBonner Thank you for your insight. It is as simple as the fact that I want to use it as a profile name in one of the services that I use. It is a very popular service, so both "rampaging" proposed by you and "rampageous" proposed by swmcdonnell below are already taken. I know that this is very weak argument, so just consider this as an answer to your question "why not". Thanks!

@trejder That seems like a use case where intentional misuses and altered words for the sake of silliness are appropriate. You could try various mutations like "rampagefullest" and so on.

I don't think so unless the context is very informal and permits made-up words.
According to Merriam-Webster, the adjective is rampageous, but that is not a commonly-used word.
It would be better to say:

"He was acting like a man on a rampage."


Or, as my mother used to say, 'running amok'.

And as @StuartF commented, the construction rampaged used attributively would suggest to most native speakers something like "that has been rapmaged," rather than "in a manner suggesting of rampage," which is the meaning of rampageous. And since rampage is intransitive, that would make the natural interpretation (of this past participle) problematic.

As per my comment to the question, in response to AndyBonner, I want to use it as a profile name. Both "rampaging" proposed Andy and "rampageous" proposed by you are already taken. I know that this is very weak argument, but... it's just is. Thanks!

@MichaelHarvey Hm... "RunningAmok" is taken, but "running-amok" not! :)

@PaulTanenbaum So... I potentially could use "rampaged" as profile name... denoting "This account has been rampaged"? :)

I would not presume to advise you about what profile name to select. I am confident that you are fully qualified to make even so weighty a decision as that all on your own.

@trejder You're still using a non-transitive verb as if it were transitive.   Someone could rampage through your account and edit it, but they could not "rampage your account".  Just as someone could scream at you but not "scream you".

What about "ManOnARampage", "WomanOnARampage", "GuyOnARampage", etc.?

@PaulTanenbaum - Thank you. I edited my answer and included your suggestion.
